# Tab Bar not hiding using UIViewController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbar

I am adding a UIViewController as PresentViewController using Tab Bar, then the view looks like:
[image]

After selecting any option, I need to hide the Tab Bar, but my screen looks like:[image]

Kindly suggest me the solution for it. I am adding a view controller:

> self.presentViewController(responseSelector, animated: true,
>   completion: nil)

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: did you set self.tabbarcontroller.tabbar.ishidden = true in responseselector v c viewillappear

Comment: yes , i tried but tabbar not hide. But want tabbar on my first screen then when i open calendar then i want to hide that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got solution for it.

```
let responseSelector =
 ResponseSelectorViewController(responseId:currentResponse.title,
 delegate:self)
         responseSelector.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext
         self.presentViewController(responseSelector, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have change 1 line of code in this.

```
 responseSelector.modalPresentationStyle = .OverFullScreen
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used the line below in the `ViewWillAppear()` function:

```
self.tabBarController!.tabBar.isHidden = true
```

And it works great.